# Parallel.ForEach with conditions

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have list of objects. Object is instance of class. Inside each object is property that hold some value:

```
List<SomeClassTask> lstSomeTaskList = new List<SomeClassTask>();

for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
     SomeClassTask tsk = new SomeClassTask();
     Thread.Sleep(500);
     tsk.SomeProperty = new Random().Next(1, 11);

     lstSomeTaskList.Add(tsk);
}
```

The next step is to run parallel task for each object

```
Parallel.ForEach(lstSomeTaskList, task => task.StartProcessing(task.SomeProperty));
```

I want to start only specific tasks like task which has value 1 (SomeProperty = 1).

This is class:

```
class SomeClassTask
{
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public void StartProcessing(int maxRange)
    {
        int rnd = new Random().Next(1, maxRange);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Parallel task -> radnom created value: " + rnd);
    }
}
```

Is it possible inside

> Parallel.ForEach

put some conditions to check some object properties?

Comment: Something like this `Parallel.ForEach(lstSomeTaskList.Where(_ => _.SomeProperty == 1), task => task.StartProcessing(task.SomeProperty));`?

Comment: You can't call `new Random()` inside a method like that without the very significant risk of getting repeated values. You should always declare as a field using `[ThreadStatic] private Random rnd = new Random();`.

Comment: Parallel.ForEach is meant for data parallelism - it's meant to partition and crunch all the data you pass to it using a limited number of tasks. What you describe is something different. You should probably *not* use Parallel.ForEach.

Comment: @Josef *what* kind of processing is `StartProcessing` doing? .NET has several high-level classes and libraries that address different parallelism or concurrency scenarios. The specifics *matter*. Obviously this isn't a data parallelism problem. Is it a *concurrency* problem? Or a dataflow problem? Agents? Why is the class named SomeClass*Task*, is it supposted to be some kind of worker or agent? High-level libraries cover all those scenarios, eg Parallel, PLINQ, Dataflow, Channels, ReactiveX. Agents come with Akka.NET or Proto.Actor

Answer (score 2):

`Parallel.ForEach` gets an `IEnumerable` as source, so you just need to filter your list object and feed it to the ForEach, something like:

```
SomeClassTask a = new SomeClassTask { SomeProperty = 1 };
SomeClassTask b = new SomeClassTask { SomeProperty = 2 };

List<SomeClassTask> lstSomeTaskList = new List<SomeClassTask> { a, b };

Parallel.ForEach(lstSomeTaskList.Where(task => task.SomeProperty == 1),
task => task.StartProcessing(task.SomeProperty));
```

**Edit**: as the comments has pointed out already, you should check this -> https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/04/revisiting-randomness/

Comment: PLINQ would be better than Parallel.ForEach in this case

Comment: He has not yet choose any answer, you are free to Post your own answer with the example you are refering too =)

Comment: To which question? The OP hasn't said what the code is supposed to be doing

Comment: What I mean is that you can contribute with an answer explaining your point of view and why OP should be using `PLINQ` instead of `Parallel.ForEach`.
The question for me was pretty clear "Is it possible to use Parallel.ForEach with conditions to check some object properties", It might be a XY problem, but I just answer what OP ask.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
IObservable<SomeClassTask> query =
    from i in Observable.Range(0, 5)
    let tsk = new SomeClassTask() { SomeProperty = _random.Next(1, 11) }
    where tsk.SomeProperty == 1
    from u in Observable.Start(() => tsk.StartProcessing(tsk.SomeProperty))
    select tsk;

IDisposable subscription = query.Subscribe();
```

Now, if you want all of the results when the query has finished then do this:

```
IDisposable subscription =
    query
        .ToList()
        .Subscribe(list => { /* use `list` here */ });
```

If you need to finish process before it completes then just do `subscription.Dispose();`.

Comment: I would love to know if the down-vote is because I didn't directly answer the OP's question or whether or not there voter thought I had a technical issue in my answer.

Comment: I would like to know too, it's an extra step adding the nuget but it seems pretty interesting Framework

Comment: @Nekeniehl - It's a framework that I have added by default to all my projects. It replaces all events for me and tasks. It's incredibly powerful and the code I've presented in this answer only scratches the surface of its power.

Comment: @Enigmativity the OP's question starts by asking for the wrong thing. This isn't a data parallelism problem so Parallel.ForEach is inappropriate. Can we translate this as a sampling problem though? PLINQ would be suitable, as there's no time component. Random activation or event generation? Then *Rx* is better with a second step to process random events that occur at random times. So *this* answer is better than *any* answer that mentions `Parallel.ForEach`